# Is there a way to convert user input to a list?

Tags: python

I am trying to convert a user input of numbers to a list where I can find the mean of those numbers but I can't figure out a way to do it as I'm only a beginner so can anyone help me out? Thanks!

```
num_input = input("Enter your numbers here: ")

numbers = [num_input]

mean = sum(numbers)/len(numbers)
print(mean)
```

Comment: Let the user separate the numbers by a specific character and then use `split()`. You also need to convert the texts to integer before summing up.

Comment: @ThomasWeller Oh ok Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps easiest by example, using a list comprehension along the way: `numbers = [float(number) for number in num_input.split()]`.

Comment: FYI: `num_input` is a string. `[num_input]` turns this into a list with one string item in it, i.e. same as `['foobar']`.

Answer (score 0):

you can take the input `string` and use the builtin method `strip` and `split` and convert them to `int` objects. see here:

please refer to python docs for further reading in the link below:

[str_methods](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str%20split#str.split)

```
num_input = input("Enter your numbers here: ")

num_input=num_input.strip().split()
new_num_list = []
for num in num_input:
    new_num_list.append(int(num))

mean = sum(new_num_list)/len(new_num_list)
print(mean)
```

Take in mind that this code snippet could `raise exceptions`! maybe you want to `except` one of them annd do something with tha `exception object`

Comment: @deceze - i was in the middle of editing and fixing. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can just split a string

```
num_input = input("Enter your numbers here: ")

numbers = [int(i) for i in num_input.split(',')]

mean = sum(numbers)/len(numbers)
print(mean)
```

Now you can pass in values like-

```
Enter your numbers here: 4, 7 , 4
5
```

Comment: Oh wow thanks so much, im still very new to coding and this helped a lot!

Comment: I am glad that you found my answer helpful.